# SQL - get default NULL value if data is not available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, common-table-expression, union-all

I got a table data as follows:

```
ID  | TYPE_ID | CREATED_DT | ROW_NUM  
=====================================
123 |   485   | 2019-08-31 | 1
123 |   485   | 2019-05-31 | 2
123 |   485   | 2019-02-28 | 3
123 |   485   | 2018-11-30 | 4
123 |   485   | 2018-08-31 | 5
123 |   485   | 2018-05-31 | 6
123 |   487   | 2019-05-31 | 1
123 |   487   | 2018-05-31 | 2
```

I would like to select 6 ROW_NUMs for each TYPE_ID, if there is missing data I need to return NULL value for CREATED_DT and the final result set should look like:

```
ID  | TYPE_ID | CREATED_DT | ROW_NUM  
=====================================
123 |   485   | 2019-08-31 | 1
123 |   485   | 2019-05-31 | 2
123 |   485   | 2019-02-28 | 3
123 |   485   | 2018-11-30 | 4
123 |   485   | 2018-08-31 | 5
123 |   485   | 2018-05-31 | 6
123 |   487   | 2019-05-31 | 1
123 |   487   | 2018-05-31 | 2
123 |   487   | NULL       | 3
123 |   487   | NULL       | 4
123 |   487   | NULL       | 5
123 |   487   | NULL       | 6
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   A.*
FROM TBL AS A 
WHERE A.ROW_NUM <= 6
UNION ALL
SELECT 
   B.*
FROM TBL AS B 
WHERE B.ROW_NUM NOT IN (SELECT ROW_NUM FROM TBL)
      AND B.ROW_NUM <= 6
```

I tried using UNION ALL and ISNULL to backfill data that is not available but it is still giving me the existing data but not the expected result. I think this can be done in a easy way by using CTE but not sure how to get this working. Can any help me in this regard.

Comment: Do entries with `ROW_NUM` actually exist for the `TYPE_ID`s with null `CREATED_DT` ?

Comment: No, ROW_NUM doesn't exist in this case, I need to create ROW_NUMs that don't exist and default CREATED_DT to NULL and ROW_NUM per TYPE_ID is always <= 6

Comment: Just to be certain, `ROW_NUM` is a part of the table, correct?

Comment: I'm generating them using ROW_NUMBER(), the table that I posted is a temp table result that i got after using ROW_NUMBER() logic

Comment: @CaitLAN Jenner any help please?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a straightforward way to do this in one query. It requires some programming logic. I'm working on a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Assuming Row_Num has at least record has at least all 6 rows... 1,2,3,4,5,6 in tbl and no fractions or 0 or negative numbers...
- we get a list of all the distinct type ID's and IDs. (Alias A)
- Then we get a distinct list of row numbers less than 7 (giving us 6 records)
- we cross join these to ensure each ID & Type_ID has all 6 rows.
- we then left join back in the base set (tbl) to get all the needed dates; where such dates exist.  As we're using left join the rows w/o a date will still persist.

.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Type_ID, C.Created_DT, B.Row_Num
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Type_ID FROM tbl) A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct row_num from tbl where Row_num < 7) B
LEFT JOIN tbl C
  on C.ID = A.ID 
 and C.Type_ID = A.Type_ID
 and C.Row_num = B.Row_num
```

Giving us:

```
+----+-----+---------+------------+---------+
|    | ID  | Type_ID | Created_DT | Row_Num |
+----+-----+---------+------------+---------+
|  1 | 123 |     485 | 2019-08-31 |       1 |
|  2 | 123 |     485 | 2019-05-31 |       2 |
|  3 | 123 |     485 | 2019-02-28 |       3 |
|  4 | 123 |     485 | 2018-11-30 |       4 |
|  5 | 123 |     485 | 2018-08-31 |       5 |
|  6 | 123 |     485 | 2018-05-31 |       6 |
|  7 | 123 |     487 | 2019-05-31 |       1 |
|  8 | 123 |     487 | 2018-05-31 |       2 |
|  9 | 123 |     487 | NULL       |       3 |
| 10 | 123 |     487 | NULL       |       4 |
| 11 | 123 |     487 | NULL       |       5 |
| 12 | 123 |     487 | NULL       |       6 |
+----+-----+---------+------------+---------+
```

Rex Tester: [Example](https://rextester.com/JAKUQ44481)

This also assumes that you'd want 1-6 for each combination of type_id and ID.  If ID's irrelevant, then simply exclude it from the join criteria.  I included it as it's an ID and seems like it's part of a key.

Comment: The problem is the OP said that Row_Num is not naturally part of the table, and it is being generated by the ROW_NUMBER() function. You could still make this technique work if you take that into account, however. I like the usage of `CROSS JOIN` - I was trying that at first and couldn't get it working.

Comment: easy enough to do w/ a 2nd CTE getting the row_num... and then use the 2nd CTE as the source...  The intent is to help; not give a full solution :P  The key to this is that Row_num 1-6 MUST exist in the same data for at least 1 record.  If not; you'll never get 6...  you'll get the max available in the table..

Comment: Great example! I learned something new. I'm leaving my answer since I spent a while working it out, and it presents a different, although perhaps overly complex, approach to solving this issue.

Comment: I would too.  There's always more than 1 way.  And not all answers work in all cases. So alternatives may help others; which is why I posted this (hopefully simpler) answer.  I also had to make lots of assumptions; which i think your response doesn't have to make

Answer (score 2):

Please reference the other answer for how you can do this using a `CROSS JOIN` - which is pretty neat. Alternatively, we can utilize the programming logic available in MS-SQL to achieve the desired results. The following approach stores distinct `ID` and `TYPE_ID` combinations inside a SQL cursor. Then it iterates through the cursor entries to ensure the appropriate amount of data is stored into a temp table. Finally, the `SELECT` is performed on the temp table and the cursor is closed. Here is a proof of concept that I validated on https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler.

```
-- Create schema for testing
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID INT,
    TYPE_ID INT,
    CREATED_DT DATE  
)

-- Populate data
INSERT INTO Test(ID, TYPE_ID, CREATED_DT)
VALUES
(123,485,'2019-08-31')
,(123,485,'2019-05-31')
,(123,485,'2019-02-28')
,(123,485,'2018-11-30')
,(123,485,'2018-08-31')
,(123,485,'2018-05-31')
,(123,487,'2019-05-31')
,(123,487,'2018-05-31');

-- Create TempTable for output
CREATE TABLE #OutputTable (
    ID INT,
    TYPE_ID INT,
    CREATED_DT DATE,
    ROW_NUM INT
)

-- Declare local variables
DECLARE @tempID INT, @tempType INT;

-- Create cursor to iterate ID and TYPE_ID
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, TYPE_ID FROM Test
    );
OPEN mycursor

-- Populate cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
INTO @tempID, @tempType;

-- Loop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE ID = @tempID AND TYPE_ID = @tempType);

    INSERT INTO #OutputTable (ID, TYPE_ID, CREATED_DT, ROW_NUM)
    SELECT ID, TYPE_ID, CREATED_DT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) 
    FROM Test
    WHERE ID = @tempID AND TYPE_ID = @tempType;

    WHILE @count < 6
    BEGIN
        SET @count = @count + 1
        INSERT INTO #OutputTable
        VALUES (@tempID, @tempType, NULL, @count);
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
    INTO @tempID, @tempType;
END

-- Close cursor
CLOSE mycursor;

-- View results
SELECT * FROM #OutputTable;
```

Note, if you have an instance where a unique combination of `ID` and `TYPE_ID` are grouped more than 6 times, the additional groupings will be included in your final result. If you must only show exactly 6 groupings, you can change that part of the query to `SELECT TOP 6 ...`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 2):

create a cte with a series and cross apply it

```
   CREATE TABLE Test (
                            ID INT,
                            TYPE_ID INT,
                            CREATED_DT DATE  
                        )

    INSERT INTO Test(ID, TYPE_ID, CREATED_DT)
    VALUES
        (123,485,'2019-08-31')
        ,(123,485,'2019-05-31')
        ,(123,485,'2019-02-28')
        ,(123,485,'2018-11-30')
        ,(123,485,'2018-08-31')
        ,(123,485,'2018-05-31')
        ,(123,487,'2019-05-31')
        ,(123,487,'2018-05-31')
;


    WITH n(n) AS
    (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < 6
    )

    ,id_n as (
                SELECT 
                DISTINCT 
                ID
                ,TYPE_ID
                ,n

                FROM 
                Test
                cross apply n
             )

    SELECT 
        id_n.ID
        ,id_n.TYPE_ID
        ,test.CREATED_DT
        ,id_n.n row_num

    FROM 
        id_n 
        left join 
                    (
                        select 
                            ID
                            ,TYPE_ID
                            ,CREATED_DT

                            ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id, type_id order by created_dt) rn 

                        from    
                        Test 

                    ) Test on Test.ID = id_n.ID and Test.TYPE_ID = id_n.TYPE_ID and id_n.n = test.rn


    drop table Test
```